# Invoice was sent to the user but I can't get any mail of stripe invoice with node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I'm developing an invoicing system using stripe.
I'm going to send invoice using stripe invoice API.
When I create an invoice, it is shown in stripe dashboard, but there is no email for the invoice. I used a function called 'sendInvoice'.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDrjtT1zdp7dc');

const invoice = await stripe.invoices.sendInvoice(
  'in_1J1Yqg2eZvKYlo..NtAx5Hl'
);
```

If I send manually in the dashboard, it works well.
Please help me, stripe experts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ncy4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Dj9.png)

Answer (score 1):

No emails are automatically sent in test mode, this is expected. Using the Dashboard, you can manually send invoice/receipt emails to your own email address only. In live mode these would be sent automatically.